# Can't find ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) project template

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am currently following a C# tutorial a higher up sent me in the company I'm doing my internship. The tutorial might be a little older because it says to "Select the ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) project template" but I can't find the exact title in project templates.

My Visual Studio:
[image]

I tried searching online but I couldn't find exactly what I needed.

The tutorial:

[image]

Comment: What tutorial are you following? How old is it? There's no such template. In fact, since ASP.NET Core 3 only .NET Core is supported, so no template includes `(.NET Core)` in its name. The screenshot you posted shows all the available ASP.NET Core templates. It seems you're following a very old tutorial that has little to do with the current ASP.NET Core projects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think it's from 2017. I wish I could give you more information on the problem but I'm still learning. I'm thinking of using the Razor Pages one but I don't know if there is any major difference. I'll try this for now and see. Thank you for your clarification!

Comment: Don't use that tutorial then, because it has little to do with current ASP.NET Core. The code generated by modern templates is *very* different, and so are the libraries. At the very least start with the official tutorials, eg [Tutorial: Get started with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=windows) and the more detailed tutorials in the [Tutorials section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/choose-web-ui?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: Can you please add link to the tutorial or is it internal one? Some further info in the tutorial might help to determine the project type. But I would guess it highly likely is ASP.NET Core Web App (MVC). A bit less likely it can be the Web API or Razor pages one.

Comment: I would go back to the person who assigned you this tutorial as it is no longer relevant. Ask them instead if there's a more up-to-date tutorial that you can follow.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is this:
[image]

You might see (Model-View-Controller), do not confuse it, it's just a structural pattern used in ASP.NET Core Web Application. You will soon learn it!
Hope it's helpful